# Extract value from different column and replace in another column

Tags: awk, perl

I need to do this:

```
##fsdfsd
##sdd-ver gen 5.5.7
Xm Gen CDS     1       148     .       +       .       Name=;created by=User;modified by=User;ID=Bm
Xm Gen CDS     149     193     .       +       .       Name=;created by=User;modified by=User;ID=Bm
Xm Gen CDS     194     279     .       +       .       Name=;created by=User;modified by=User;ID=Bm
Xm Gen CDS     280     412     .       +       .       Name=;created by=User;modified by=User;ID=Bm
Xm Gen CDS     413     499     .       +       .       Name=;created by=User;modified by=User;ID=Bm
Xm Gen CDS     500     702     .       +       .       Name=;created by=User;modified by=User;ID=Bm
Xm Gen extracted region        1       148     .       +       .       Name=Extracted region from gi|371442828|gb|JH557032.1|;Extracted interval="437225 <- 437372";ID=Bm
Xm Gen extracted region        149     193     .       +       .       Name=Extracted region from gi|371442828|gb|JH557032.1|;Extracted interval="436969 <- 437013";ID=Bm
Xm Gen extracted region        194     279     .       +       .       Name=Extracted region from gi|371442828|gb|JH557032.1|;Extracted interval="435418 <- 435503";ID=Bm
Xm Gen extracted region        280     412     .       +       .       Name=Extracted region from gi|371442828|gb|JH557032.1|;Extracted interval="435209 <- 435341";ID=Bm
Xm Gen extracted region        413     499     .       +       .       Name=Extracted region from gi|371442828|gb|JH557032.1|;Extracted interval="434376 <- 434462";ID=Bm
Xm Gen extracted region        500     702     .       +       .       Name=Extracted region from gi|371442828|gb|JH557032.1|;Extracted interval="434084 <- 434286";ID=Bm
```

Replace (Xm Gen CDS) rows with values present in (Xm Gen extracted region) rows. i.e first row ($4 column:1 is replaced with 437225 value and $5 column:148 is replaced with 437372, in row 2 ($4 column:149 replaced with 436969, $5 column:193 replaced with 437013 and so on) and print output like below

```
##gff-version 2
##source-version geneious 5.5.7
Xm Gen CDS     437225       437372     .       +       .       Name=;created by=User;modified by=User;ID=Bm
Xm Gen CDS     436969     437013     .       +       .       Name=;created by=User;modified by=User;ID=Bm
Xm Gen CDS     435418     435503     .       +       .       Name=;created by=User;modified by=User;ID=Bm
Xm Gen CDS     435209     435341     .       +       .       Name=;created by=User;modified by=User;ID=Bm
Xm Gen CDS     434376     434462     .       +       .       Name=;created by=User;modified by=User;ID=Bm
Xm Gen CDS     434084     434286     .       +       .       Name=;created by=User;modified by=User;ID=Bm
Xm Gen extracted region        1       148     .       +       .       Name=Extracted region from gi|371442828|gb|JH557032.1|;Extracted interval="437225 <- 437372";ID=Bm
Xm Gen extracted region        149     193     .       +       .       Name=Extracted region from gi|371442828|gb|JH557032.1|;Extracted interval="436969 <- 437013";ID=Bm
Xm Gen extracted region        194     279     .       +       .       Name=Extracted region from gi|371442828|gb|JH557032.1|;Extracted interval="435418 <- 435503";ID=Bm
Xm Gen extracted region        280     412     .       +       .       Name=Extracted region from gi|371442828|gb|JH557032.1|;Extracted interval="435209 <- 435341";ID=Bm
Xm Gen extracted region        413     499     .       +       .       Name=Extracted region from gi|371442828|gb|JH557032.1|;Extracted interval="434376 <- 434462";ID=Bm
Xm Gen extracted region        500     702     .       +       .       Name=Extracted region from gi|371442828|gb|JH557032.1|;Extracted interval="434084 <- 434286";ID=Bm
```

Comment: Please take some time to read the editing help (click on the yellow `?` on the top right of the question editor). In particular, indent data snippets with four spaces in the editor (use the code button or press `Ctrl+K`).

Comment: Just to add to @Gilles's comment, here is a [reference for editing](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit complicated variant, however it works pretty well.

```
head -2 file 
join <(grep "Xm Gen CDS" file | cat -n) \
     <(grep "Xm Gen extracted region" file | cat -n) | \
     sed 's/^[0-9]* //;s/CDS [0-9]*\s[0-9]*\(\s.*interval="\([0-9]*\)\s<-\s\([0-9]*\)\)/CDS\t\2\t\3\t\1/;s/ Xm Gen extracted.*//'
grep "Xm Gen extracted region" file
```

to run it as a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1"
head -2 "$FILE"
join <(grep "Xm Gen CDS" "$FILE" | cat -n) \
     <(grep "Xm Gen extracted region" "$FILE" | cat -n) | \
     sed 's/^[0-9]* //;s/CDS [0-9]*\s[0-9]*\(\s.*interval="\([0-9]*\)\s<-\s\([0-9]*\)\)/CDS\t\2\t\3\t\1/;s/ Xm Gen extracted.*//'
grep "Xm Gen extracted region" "$FILE"
```

Comment: It would be great..if there is any perl script from the computer experts

Comment: Great use of join & grep. Can you please tell me, how to run this as shell script, getting input from user and giving output.

Comment: @bioman just copy the second part to a script file, make it executable with `chmod +x scriptname` and execute as `./scriptname file_with_data`.

Comment: thanks.Is it possible to get perl code. Because Xm Gen CDS line may differ as (eg.Ym Genx CDS) in various formats, so I cannot use grep

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not good enough in perl. May be someone else will help you.